# Does it mean something wrong when I have too many Mockito when().thenReturn() to simulate the case?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to do unit testing using Mockito to simulate the case. In the testing class, we only have one public method. So to simulate different cases, I have to mock a lot of details of the data. Please see below:

```
when(config.booleanValue(param1)).thenReturn(true);
        when(config.doubleValue(param2).thenReturn(9999.0);
        when(myCalendar.getAppointmentNumber()).thenReturn(3);
        when(location1.getLatitude()).thenReturn(90.0);
        when(location2.getLongitude()).thenReturn(90.0);
        when(location1.getLowerBoundary()).thenReturn(12.0);
        when(address1.getId()).thenReturn(1);
        when(address1.popularity()).thenReturn(0.6);
        when(people.getLocation(any(LocalDate.class))).thenReturn(location1);
        when(people.getAddresses(any(LocalDate.class))).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(address1));
        when(location2.getLatitude()).thenReturn(90.3);
        when(location2.getLongitude()).thenReturn(90.3);
        when(location2.getId()).thenReturn(1);
        when(customer.getLocation(any(LocalDate.class))).thenReturn(location2);
        when(myCalendar.getPrevAppointment()).thenReturn(appointment1);
        when(myCalendar.getNextAppointment()).thenReturn(appointment2);
        when(appointment1.to(appointment2)).thenReturn(15.0);
        when(appointment2.to(any(Location.class))).thenReturn(9.0);
```

Using Mockito like this seems to be something wrong to me. Or I am thinking too much. Please lecture me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. I had to test a function that executed another function for each cell in a 2d map/image. The testing function got really complicated and large. In the end i split the class into 2 classes. One for the iteration and one for the per cell calculation. Then it was much simpler to test in separation.

Can you split your class into simpler classes?

Comment: I personally think the class shouldn't be split for my case, cause it is doing one thing just falls into different cases for different scenarios.

Comment: You could also move the different scenarios to different functions and test them separately. And to test the main function you could spy on the object and overwrite the scenario functions.

Comment: i did, but thats private method. i recall i saw somewhere that we shouldnt test private methods. right?

Comment: Sure, but if the private method is important enough to test on its own or useful to reuse, you can extract it as a public method of a new class.

Then you can test the parent class with a mock of the new class and test the new class on its own.

Comment: thanks for the advice. However, I have one question. Could you please give more detail about extracting it as a public method of a new class? That confuse me. I mean if I can extract it as a public method of a parent class and expose it, why don't I directly make it public? Could you give me a little bit more guidance of this idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is an example I did:
https://github.com/Orchaldir/FantasyWorldSimulation/commit/7489657911af82143958f19e064147110583aa18

I extracted prepareSourceValues() & interpolateCell() from MapInterpolator to CellInterpolator and made them public. And then I tested them separately. 

Why? The function tryInterpolate() was original too complex to test, because I had to also test what happened in the extracted functions. Now I can mock them and only test tryInterpolate(). Plus CellInterpolator could become an interface with multiple implantations.